# find index where element change sign from 0 to 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame like below, where I want to find index where element goes from 0 to 1.

Below code gets all the instances I want, however it also includes cases where sign changes from -1 to 0, which I don't want.

```
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame([0,1,1,1,0,1,0,-1,0])
df[np.sign(df[0]).diff(periods=1).eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
    0
1   1
5   1
8   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition:

```
filtered = df[np.sign(df[0]).diff(1).eq(1) & np.sign(df[0]).eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
   0
1  1
5  1
```